# pull subject ids after detecting characters matching a string

Tags: r, string, dplyr, pull, grepl

Please help me pull subject id's after determining a list of participants who do not contain specified characters. e.g:

data:

```
df <- structure (list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"), edta_codes = c("4EDTA-3M783316", "4EDTA-3M2897865", "4EDTA-M280934", "4EDTA-3M286549","MCF -3M289684", "NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -6L))
```

Code to test if character is in string:

```
df$edta_codes[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_codes)]
```

Different method:

```
str_detect(df$edta_codes,"4EDTA-3")
```

Both give me the result I want but from here I want to show the subject ids that do not have the specified string, including those with NA (i.e. in this case - 191-3457, 191-1245, 191-2365 are all different from the specified characters). I have tried using pull after each of the above codes and they both did not work.

Please help.

Comment: `df[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_code), ]$subject_id` ?

Comment: Hello. Just this error: Error in df[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_code), ]$subject_id: 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: FYI, your code is using partial matches to `edta_code` but the real column name is `edta_codes` (plural). R is fixing your mistake for you but it is bad practice. (Set `options(warnPartialMatchAttr=TRUE)` to see this as a warning when it happens.)

Comment: Thandi, the code does not produce an error with this sample data, suggesting your data is not quite the same.

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
df[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_codes),'subject_id']
#[1] "191-3457" "191-1245" "191-2365"
```

If you want to return also the codes, then,

```
df[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_codes),]

#  subject_id    edta_codes
#3   191-3457 4EDTA-M280934
#5   191-1245 MCF -3M289684
#6   191-2365            NA
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know I can take it a step further and return the subject_id as well as its incorrect code/NA?

Comment: Just remove the `subject_id`, i.e. `df[!grepl("4EDTA-3", df$edta_codes),]`

Comment: Yes, but that only returns the incorrect codes, I need both the incorrect codes and the subject id matching to each. So e.g. it should return ```191-3457 4EDTA-M280934``` in maybe a table or any format.

Comment: I edited my answer. Have a look

Comment: Oh I now see what you meant with your previous comment. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it.